# PHP, Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

I wanted to build a super-simple login-script with a text-file. Text-file contains

```
password    username    name
```

Between the password, username and name is a tab. I read the file, explode it by tab, and then check the user input against the lines.

But I always get (one) `Undefined offset` error. I think it is because of the explode function, but I don't know why...

Here's my code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['login_inputEmail']) || !empty($_POST['login_inputPassword']))
{
    $log = 0; //not logged in
    $username = $_POST['login_inputEmail'];
    $password = $_POST['login_inputPassword'];
    $userdatei = fopen ("documents/user.txt","r");
    while (!feof($userdatei))
       {
       $zeile = fgets($userdatei,800);
       $userdata = explode("\t", $zeile);
       if ($username == $userdata[1] && $password == trim($userdata[0]))
          {
          $log = 1; //logged in
          }
       }
    fclose($userdatei);
}
```

Comment: Could be you have a problem with the file encoding. Can you do a `var_dump($userdata)` after the `explode` operation?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399509/getting-rid-of-php-notice-undefined-offset)

Comment: @Benny yes i can do that, looks like  `array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "142" [1]=> string(18) "bla@blub.com" [2]=> string(11) "Mustermann " }` ... on some lines I have something like this `string(6) "B�hr "`

Comment: in which line does the error appear??

Comment: on the `explode` line. thank you very much for your help, now it works!

Comment: Simply change if condition to `if (count($userdata) > 1 && ...` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add is_array() and isset() in your code to avoid errors. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399509/getting-rid-of-php-notice-undefined-offset)

```
 if(!empty($_POST['login_inputEmail']) || !empty($_POST['login_inputPassword']))
 {
     $log = 0; //not logged in
     $username = $_POST['login_inputEmail'];
     $password = $_POST['login_inputPassword'];
     $userdatei = fopen ("documents/user.txt","r");
     while (!feof($userdatei))
     {
        $zeile = fgets($userdatei,800);
        $userdata = explode("\t", $zeile);
        if(is_array($userdata))
        {
           if(isset($userdata[1]) && isset($userdata[0]))
           {
              if ($username == $userdata[1] && $password == trim($userdata[0]))
              {
                 $log = 1; //logged in
              }
           }
        }
     }
    fclose($userdatei);
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399509/getting-rid-of-php-notice-undefined-offset